# JQuery Validate Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validate on a JQuery Mobile form that has a listview with an Auto Complete option that is created dynamically.

I get this error if you try and type into the auto complete field, once validation is active.

I can see that the problem is related to the form that jQuery Mobile creates to hold the filter input but I can not figure out how to stop jQuery Validate from validating the field.

I can reproduce it using 
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/finbarmurphy/9xy4v044/)

(Press Validate and then type in the filter box)

Any suggestions appreciated

Thanks

```
<body>
<script>
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: '[data-type="search"]'

    });
</script>
<form>
    <input required>
    <ul id="ac" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search cars...">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="$('#ac').attr('data-role','listview');$('#ac').listview();$('form').validate();">Validate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using jQM 1.3? or newer version?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your whole problem is being cause by the dynamic HTML that is created by the `listview()` function.  Inspecting the DOM reveals that this dynamically creates a new `<form>` container.  Since you've placed `listview` within your `<form>` container, you now have `<form></form>` nested within `<form></form>`, which is very invalid HTML, and the whole reason the jQuery Validate plugin is working so unexpectedly.

The solution is to place your listview element outside of your `<form>` container.

Comment: "you now have a <form></form> nested within a <form></form> which is very invalid HTML and the whole reason the jQuery Validate plugin is working so unexpectedly" this part solved my problem

Comment: beware, some* plugins add a `<form>` programmatically, and make validate fail exactly for this.   

[http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php]*