# Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined while inline editing Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-validate

I'm doing inline editing in a kendoui grid.  When I enter a character into one of the editable fields, this error appears in browser debugging console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

it occurs in `jquery.validate.min.js`:

```
prototype:{init:function(){function e(e){var i=t.data(this[0].form,"validator"),s="on"+e.type.replace(/^validate/,"");**i.settings[s]**&&i.settings[s].call(i,this[0],e)
```

I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what it could be.  I've googled for this error, and nothing matches.

Update:  I've set the browser debugger to pause on exceptions.  I get this one first  (which is not appearing in the console)

```
    stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'webkitMatchesSelector' on 'Element': ':text, [type='password'], [type='file'], select, textarea, [type='number'], [type='search'] ,[type='tel'], [type='url'], [type='email'], [type='datetime'], [type='date'], [type='month'], [type='week'], [type='time'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='range'], [type='color'] ' is not a valid selector.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.at.matchesSelector (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21:15239)
    at Function.x.extend.filter (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:23506)
    at ft (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:24059)
    at x.fn.extend.is (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:21589)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js:16:20918)
    at HTMLFormElement.x.event.dispatch (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:14129)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:10873)
    at Object.x.event.trigger (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:13255)
    at Object.e.event.trigger (/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2:6732)"
```

This is the one I see in the console.  Nothing on the call stack tells me what it's related to in my code:

```
    stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at e (/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js:16:4816)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js:16:20926)
    at HTMLFormElement.x.event.dispatch (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:14129)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:10873)
    at Object.x.event.trigger (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:13255)
    at Object.e.event.trigger (/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2:6732)
    at Object.x.event.simulate (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:16639)
    at HTMLDocument.r (/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:19701)
    at s.extend._focusin (/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js:21:8634)
    at s.extend._step (/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js:21:10637)"
```

Comment: The excerpt you included indicates the frame where the actual error occurred, but that's not very helpful here because it doesn't give us any context of your code. Try to get the call stack for the error and follow it from this frame back until you get to the first frame that contains familiar code (i.e. your code). If you can't find any code that's familiar, post the relevant HTML and JS from your application that is failing.

Comment: Could be anything.  Like the first comment is trying to tell you, we'd need to see _your_ relevant code.  The error could be that you attached one the methods of the plugin to an invalid selector or that you've improperly created the settings parameters.  Show us your call to `.validate()`, the relevant ***rendered*** HTML, and any other methods from the plugin that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had a form nested within another form as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509958/jquery-validate-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-settings-of-undefined?rq=1).  Thanks Sparky