# How to Debug and resolve - JQuery Cannot read property 'Settings' of Undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, debugging, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I have a very weird problem, and I am looking for guidance on how to best debug similar problems in the future.

I have a Simple form that deletes the current active order.
When the user clicks the button, i open a Modal and ask for confirmation.

```
<form action="/KundeOrdre/Slet" id="Form-SletKundeOrdre" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="1010101010" name="KundeOrdre.Hoved.OrdreNummer" />
    <input type="submit" id="sletKundeOrdre" data-target="Form-SletKundeOrdre" value="Slet" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" />
</form>
```

I have two Javascript methods in place.
1. To catch the click on the button and show the Modal instead
2. Catch the confirm click and submit the from

```
// Show Confirm Dialog when clicking the Delete Buttont
$(function () {
    $('#sletKundeOrdre').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-confirmDeleteOrder').modal('show');       
    });
});

// Bind a Listener to the Confirm button
$('#modal-confirmDeleteOrder').on('click', 'button#confirm', function (e) {
    $('#Form-SletKundeOrdre').submit();
});
```

When i run this setup and click confirm in the Model, i get a Javascript error and the Form is not submitted.

```
jquery.validate.js:1068 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

I am looking for good ideas on how to debug a situation like this.
A plugin is giving me trouble and im assuming its on my end.

This form is included in a page that consists of 2 Partial Views, each containing multiple forms.
This particular form is in the 2nd View and is nr 3 out of 4 forms on that page.

Another observation:
The 4th Form in the same View is a table containing rows. This error happens when the table contains zero rows.
If i add a single row to the 4th Form, this form (3rd) works as expected.

I do not understand why submitting my 3rd form is in any way related to my 4th form.

**Update:**
I seem to have resolved the issue.
I had an Input button inside my form, that had a link to the 'GemKundeOrdreLinjer' form (my 4th form).

```
<input type="button" id="gemKundeOrdre" value="@Resources.Panel_KundeOrdreGem" form="GemKundeOrdreLinjer" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" />
```

Moving this button outside my form, solved issue for now.
This leaves me with a display issue about buttons, but ill keep this Question updated

Comment: How are you debugging your client scripts now? IE, Chrome have debugging possibilities.

Comment: I am using the Debugger in Chrome. I believe i have confirmed that my code is working as it should. But the JQuery Validation code is triggered and cases an error and im not sure how to fix that. I am not invoking it myself.

Comment: Perhaps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509958/jquery-validate-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-settings-of-undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509958/jquery-validate-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-settings-of-undefined) could be helpfull to you. Perhaps because your code is pretty dynamic with all those partials. Might be you are having a form within a form issue.

Comment: Also what you could do is make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the issue. Sometimes it's helpfull because your isolating the issue from the rest of the code.